# Error in Entity Framework relationships mapping

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-6

I got the following EF6 mapping

```
namespace Model
{
    [Serializable]
    [Table("PROVISION")]
    public class Provision
    {
        [Key, Column("ID_PROVISION", Order = 1), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public virtual long Id { get; set; }

        [Column("ID_PROVISION_TYPE")]
        public virtual int IdProvisionType { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("IdProvisionType")]
        public virtual ProvisionType ProvisionType { get; set; }
    }

    public class ProvisionType 
    {
        [Key, Column("ID_PROVISION_TYPE", Order = 1), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

However, I get the following error:

> Provision_ProvisionType_Target_Provision_ProvisionType_Source: the types of all properties in the dependent role of a referential constraint must be the same as the corresponding property types in the principal role. The type of property 'Id' on entity 'Provision' does not match the type of property 'Id' on entity 'ProvisionType' in the referential constraint 'Provision_ProvisionType'.

As you can see the foreign key and the referenced primary key are the same type. The thing is that it worked fine on EF4, but as soon as I updated to EF6, I started getting this error, and the system is huge and full of this same scenario.

Edit: forgot to mention it is a .net 4.0 project

Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: Can't reproduce the exception using your classes in EF 6.2.0. Only if I actually make the types different.

Comment: the presented ids has diferent types. int and long, however the foreign key and the id on the related class has the same type

Comment: It looks to me like if `Provision_ProvisionType` is incorrectly joining by both `Id` instead of `IdProvisionType` and `Id`. Why would it say "The type of property 'Id' on entity 'Provision' does not match" otherwise?

Comment: @Andrew Yes, that's the weird thing. All I know is that the code *as shown* is OK.

Comment: @jhonatanteixeira, have you looked for `Provision_ProvisionType` in the entire code?

Answer (score 0):

`ID_PROVISION` is primary key, so the `ForeignKey` use id from `ID_PROVISION` against id `ID_PROVISION_TYPE` key (key against key), so you must to define same type.

Try this:

```
namespace Model
{
    [Serializable]
    [Table("PROVISION")]
    public class Provision
    {
        [Key, Column("ID_PROVISION", Order = 1), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public virtual long Id { get; set; }

        [Key,Column("ID_PROVISION_TYPE")]
        public virtual int IdProvisionType { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("IdProvisionType")]
        public virtual ProvisionType ProvisionType { get; set; }
    }

    public class ProvisionType 
    {
        [Key, Column("ID_PROVISION_TYPE", Order = 1), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: They *are* the same type. And making `IdProvisionType` part of the primary key doesn't solve anything (on the contrary) and isn't related to this type problem.

Comment: DId you try it?
I know that ForeignKey use only key-columnn

Comment: A foreign key should *refer to* a PK column (in EF6). Of course it shouldn't necessarily be a PK column itself.

Comment: Yes,of course!!! please read my answer, I refer define ID_PROVISION_TYPE as PK, not the ForeignKey as PK!

Comment: It's about `Provision.IdProvisionType`. No need to make it part of the PK. That changes all kinds of things OP is not waiting for. `ProvisionType.IdProvisionType` must be PK, and already was.

Comment: Well, what you say, I know otherwise